# Solving a system of linear equations using Cramer's Rule

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, determinant

I'm trying to solve the following Cramer's system 
$$AX=B \rightarrow \left\{\begin{matrix}x + y + z = 1\\ ax + by + cz = m\\ a^{2}x + b^{2}y + c^{2}z = m^{2}\\ 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

I tried to find the determinant of the A matrix:
$$\begin{vmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\ a & b & c\\ a^{2} & b^{2} & c^{2}\end{vmatrix}\underset{l_{2}-al_{1}, l_{3}-a^{2}l_{2}} {\rightarrow}\begin{vmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & b-a & c-a\\ 0 & b^{2}-a^{2} & c^{2}-a^{2}\end{vmatrix}\underset{l_{3}-(b+a)l_{2}} {\rightarrow}\begin{vmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & b-a & c-a\\ 0 & 0 & (c^{2}-a^{2}) - (c-a)\cdot(b+a) \end{vmatrix}$$

It seems like my determinant is wrong, because I'm getting the wrong solution to the system... Since the B matrix later substitutes a column in each of the 3 different matrices in the rule, the determinant obtained should be the same, i.e: 
$$\det(A_{b_{1}}) = \begin{vmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\ m & b & c\\ m^{2} & b^{2} & c^{2}\end{vmatrix}$$
We would end up swapping **a** for **m**.

I've tried re-doing the problem over and over, but I end up getting the same wrong solution and I need help...

Comment: It is well-known that this Vandermonde determinant is equal to $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$, which is equal to what you find.

Comment: The entry $D_{23}$ in the 3rd determinant should be $(c-a)(b+a)$ instead of $(c-a)$ but it doesn't harme the result...

Comment: @bernard never heard of it :( I'm studying linear algebra on my own.

Comment: You can take a look at  [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix).

Comment: @Bernard thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the determinant
$$
d = \begin{vmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & b-a & c-a\\ 0 & b^{2}-a^{2} & c^{2}-a^{2}\end{vmatrix}
$$
can be easily found by cofactor expansion along the first column, you quickly get
$$
\begin{split}
d &= 1 \cdot \begin{vmatrix}b-a & c-a\\ b^2-a^2 & c^2-a^2\end{vmatrix} \\
  &= (b-a)(c^2-a^2) - (b^2-a^2)(c-a) \\
  &= (b-a)(c-a)[c+a - (b+a)] \\
  &= (b-a)(c-a)(c-b).
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick for me!